# Custom render field for lightning

Tags: lightning, custom-field, lightning-renderer

**Scenario**

I've have multiple images categorised like before, after, extra images. And I want to display them together in Record page, ofc with customisation like in HTML grid something as I need some space between those and I even want to add some text below the Images for identifying them.

**What I tried?**

I tried one thing like making formula for displaying the image and storing the url in one field but I can not do complex customisation like added description or multiple images like I wanted.

I also searched for few things but ended up results only for visualforce pages. I've very less experience of customising Salesforce, so maybe I'm trying to search wrong term.
But I hope you get my point.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what we have coded with SharinPix from the AppExchange. It requires to get a Custom Object to store all the image information and the metadata you want to add there. 
Then you will have to code the viewer for those custom object as a grid and be aware that optimisation on displayed image should be require as well to get user a good experience. Alternatively you can also rely on AppExchange offers that are offering this  as out-of-the-box on which you can make personnalisation.